# Python Django: Filled in form field always throws error "This field is required" on POST

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a form where I just included one textbox and a submit button. Everytime when I fill in the textbox and try to submit the form validation fails and the error message "This field is required" gets thrown.

**add_stock.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<h1>Add Stock</h1>
<form action="{% url 'add_stock' %}"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="ticker">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</form>

{{ form.errors }}
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
def add_stock(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StockForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, ('Stock has been added'))
            return redirect('overview') 
        return render(request, 'add_stock.html', {'form':form}) 
    return render(request, 'add_stock.html', {})
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Stock(models.Model):
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    #trade_date = models.DateField(blank=True, default='')
    #quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default='')
    #unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, default='')
    #brokerage = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2, blank=True, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ticker
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Stock

class StockForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        fields =  ["ticker"]
        #fields =  ["ticker", "trade_date", "quantity", "unit_price", "brokerage"]
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHOey.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should set `name` attribute

```
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="ticker" id="ticker">
```